# Can I autosave open unsaved files in TextPad

Tags: autosave, textpad

I have a habit of opening a lot of text windows in TextPad, say about 20, or more, all unsaved.

Several days later I go through them and save the ones I need/want.

This works fine, except when my computer crashes ... and it crashes when I play videos, it seems, but only sometimes.  Otherwise, it works fine for days with no problem.
When it crashes, all my unsaved windows in TextPad get lost.

Hence, I want to find a way to keep them even if they were unsaved.  How?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the "Preferences\Backup\Automatically save" option will be of use to you.

Comment: ah well this feature seems to force you to save the file, as in give the file a name and save it.  I suppose that'll work towards my goal.  I tend to leave multiple unsaved/unnamed files open, and while this option adds the inconvenience of saving the file, it does work... as long as I use it.